# PHP save the file using the link found by the block ID on the page

Tags: php

On the page https://data.mos.ru/opendata/61241/ the first url with parameter "export/get?id=" contains the last actual link to download the open data csv file //op.mos.ru/EHDWSREST/catalog/export/get?id=989116 .

The problem is that the digital ending of the url after each update is different and is not known in advance.

I have a script that works and allows me to save a file at a pre-known file url (but it only saves the old version of the file, not the current one):

```
<?php
function downloadJs($file_url, $save_to)
{
    $content = file_get_contents($file_url);
    file_put_contents($save_to, $content);
} 
downloadJs('https://op.mos.ru/EHDWSREST/catalog/export/get?id=989116', realpath("./img/feeds") . '/61241.zip');
$zip = new ZipArchive;$zip->open('./img/feeds/61241.zip');$zip->extractTo('./img/feeds/61241');$zip->close();
$directory = './img/feeds/61241/'; if ($handle = opendir($directory)) { while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) { $dd = explode($fileName); $newfile = '61241.csv'; rename($directory . $fileName, $directory.$newfile); } closedir($handle); }
echo "Ok!";
?>
```

I need to change this PHP script so that on the page https://data.mos.ru/opendata/61241/ first determined the first link to the download file by the parameter "export/get?id=", where the link is located.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you understand what you mean.
we have:

`<a target="_blank" href="//op.mos.ru/EHDWSREST/catalog/export/get?id=989116" onclick="yaCounter29850344.reachGoal('download_csv')...`

Perhaps we will use a little regex to get that id.
Let's say you already have its html with `file_get_contents`:

```
preg_match('#get\?id=(\d+)".* onclick="[^"]+csv[^"]+"#', $html, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // 989116
```